# moment js 2 dates difference showing as NaN

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I am trying to compare 2 dates and find the no.of months difference. But i am not able to get it. It is giving NaN in console.log.

Here is my code

```
        var interestStartDate = moment(createdAtMoment).format('YYYY, DD, MM') // (2020, 23, 05)
        var interestEndDate = moment().format('YYYY, DD, MM') // (2021, 06, 01)
        console.log('interestStartDate: ', interestStartDate) 
        console.log('interestEndDate: ', interestEndDate)
        console.log( moment(interestEndDate).diff(moment(interestStartDate), 'months', true))
```

console.log, displayed like below

[image]

Comment: Specify the format while passing into moment constructor, example - `moment('2020, 06, 01', 'YYYY, DD, MM')`

Comment: Thanks, it worked now after adding the format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`moment().format()` result is the string, but the `diff()` is the method of `moment`.

So you should remove `.format()` to make `interestStartDate` and `interestEndDate` types to `Moment` object.

```
        var interestStartDate = moment(createdAtMoment)
        var interestEndDate = moment()
        console.log('interestStartDate: ', interestStartDate) 
        console.log('interestEndDate: ', interestEndDate)
        console.log( moment(interestEndDate).diff(moment(interestStartDate), 'months', true))
```

Answer (score 0):

worked after adding format.

```
            var interestStartDate = moment(createdAtMoment).format('YYYY, DD, MM')
            var interestEndDate = moment().format('YYYY, DD, MM')
            console.log('interestStartDate: ', interestStartDate)
            console.log('interestEndDate: ', interestEndDate)
            console.log(  moment(interestEndDate,'YYYY, DD, MM').diff(moment(interestStartDate, 'YYYY, DD, MM'), 'months', true))
```